# Compress a string with incremental appends / updates

Tags: javascript, compression

I'm trying to find a compression method that can handle incremental updates, assuming a perfect connection between client and server.

For example, a naive way to do this would be to store words and send their index sequence. Consider the following text that is captured in chunks.

```
Text stream: "quick quick brown brown fox brown fox jumped over" ...

Time 0:
Plaintext: "quick quick brown"
Compressed: "quick,brown;0,0,1"

Time 1:
Plaintext: "brown fox"
Compressed: "fox;1,2"

Time 2:
Plaintext: "brown fox jumped over"
Compressed: "jumped,over;1,2,3,4"
```

In this case, at Time 1, the client-side already knows that the server received the first dictionary, and doesn't need to send words it already knows.

Is there a specific name and/or method for this type of compression? I specifically want a client-side JS solution, but if someone could point me to a place to start looking for algorithms like this, that would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not take a look at zlib/deflate which is block based ("window" in zlib term). There is a ported solution available [here](https://github.com/nodeca/pako).

Comment: Take a look at the [LZ4 Streaming API](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/wiki/LZ4-Streaming-API-Basics), it does exactly what you want. There is also a [JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4).